# Run commands in newly opened terminal

Tags: python

I want to open a new terminal through python. In that newly spawned terminal I want to execute commands. I've checked multiple posts which are suggested through similar questions but I couldn't find the answer.

I've tried this:

```py
import os
    
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'cd /home/john/Documents; echo 'writing to file' > testfile.txt'")
```

The new terminal spawns but the commands don't get executed in the new terminal.

```
❯ python3 TestOpenTerminal.py 
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
# Error: Failed to execute child process “cd” (No such file or directory)
```

How can I do this? Thx

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin command, and I don't believe you are running a shell.

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` command don't work with gnome-terminal command, you need to use the option `--working-directory=/path/to/dir`.
The `-e` option is deprecated, you need to use `--` followed by the command, like `gnome-terminal -- 'command'`.
To manipulate files the only way I could make work is using `bash` and option `-c` before the command.
So the command you want to do is:

> gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/john/Documents -- bash -c "echo 'writing to file' > testfile.txt"

I really recommend you to use the fabric library to use with terminal commands, it works with all systems and returns the output to you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you really want to open a terminal, but you could just open the file through python and write with it. Try to use the open() and write() functions.

Comment: Thanks but I want to execute the commands in the newly spawned terminal. The commands I provided are just examples, I want to run different commands in the working version.

Comment: I don't think spawning terminals to this is a good solution, try to use fabric library, it's very useful to run terminal commands, it also returns the output to you

Answer (score -1):

Look closely at your command. Your opening single quote is closed by the single quotes around 'writing to file' and that causes a mess.

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'cd /home/john/Documents; echo 'writing to file' > testfile.txt'")
```

Also, the default behavior of gnome-terminal is to close when complete. You can keep it open by editing the profile as follows...

In gnome-terminal, go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title. Click the Command tab. Select Hold the terminal from the drop-down menu labelled When command exits. You should create a new profile for that and execute with

gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NAMEOFTHEPROFILE -e command